# Apply dictionary look-up function to compare pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping, apply

I'd like to apply a function to two columns (A and B) of a pandas dataframe that tests if each of their values match the same result in a dictionary. I'd like it to return the result to a third column.

I've tried the code below and close variants but I keep getting errors and I think there's something fundemental that I'm not understanding about the data structure. Can anyone explain where am I going wrong? I can imagine cumbersome alternative ways to do this but I'm sure there must be an elegant solution.

```
def do_they_match(A1,A2):
    if A1 in dictionary and A2 in dictionary and dictionary[A1] == dictionary[A2]:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: do_they_match(x['A'],x['B']))
## also tried ## 
df = df.assign(link=lambda x: do_they_match(x['A'],x['B']))
```

For context, the errors I get are `IndexError: ('A', 'occurred at index A')` or `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed` for the alternative code on the last line.The values in both dataframe columns and in the dictionary are all strings.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible you meant `df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: do_they_match(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error because you are trying to apply the function passing parameters of data from the same ***row*** but with your syntax, the `x` in `lambda x` refers to a ***column***.  Thus, the code `x['A']` is actually trying to take `A` as a row index for the current column `x` being processed. Each of the column in the dataframe will take turn as the column to be processed in this `apply` statement.

You have to make use of the `axis=` parameter of [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to instruct Pandas to take row-wise operations by passing `axis=1`.

[Official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) has explanation of the `axis` parameter:

> **axis** {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 **Axis along which the
> function is applied**:
>
> 0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
>
> **1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.**

The default value is `axis=0` to apply function to *each* column.

To get through the error, you can add `axis=1` to your code:

```
df['match'] = df.apply(lambda x: do_they_match(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)
```

---

**Better solution** is that you don't need to define the custom function and probably you can map the dictionary values by using the Pandas function [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) such as follows:

```
df['match'] = (df['A'].map(dictionary) == df['B'].map(dictionary)).astype(int)
```

We use [`astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to convert the boolean result to integer `0` (for False) and `1` (for True)

For example, we have the following dataframe and `dictionary`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 'B': ['y1', 'y2', 'y3']})

    A   B
0  x1  y1
1  x2  y2
2  x3  y3


dictionary = {'x1': 'apple', 'y1': 'orange', 'x2': 'banana', 'y2': 'banana', 'x3': 'peach'}
```

When we apply the code, we get:

```
df['match'] = (df['A'].map(dictionary) == df['B'].map(dictionary)).astype(int)

print(df)

    A   B  match
0  x1  y1      0
1  x2  y2      1
2  x3  y3      0
```

Comment: You are correct, including that I could do this more efficiently using just the map function. In addition, the map function solution operates considerably faster on my data! Thank you SeaBean!

Comment: @JamieGorzynski   Welcome!  That's right!  `apply` with custom function is relatively slow.  Always seek for the built-in Pandas function to use if avaialble.  Use `.apply` only as the last resort.